# `curl` outputs random characters

Tags: command-line, curl

If I run:

```
curl http://files.unity3d.com/levi/unity-editor-5.2.2f1+20151018_amd64.deb
```

It continuously outputs random characters, then the program completes.

I tried reinstalling it, but to no avail.

Works with `wget` though.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the exact command you're running.

Comment: Maybe don't try to download and print binary files?

Comment: what is the output when you run `which curl`

Answer (score 4):

In curl, you need to specify that you need the downloaded file to be kept intact as it was in the server, i.e, a `*.mp3` will be downloaded as `*.mp3` and not as the one shown in your screenshot. From `curl --help`:

```
-O, --remote-name   Write output to a file named as the remote file
```

So, to download the mentioned file you just have to add `-O` to the command, i.e.,

```
curl -O http://files.unity3d.com/levi/unity-editor-5.2.2f1+20151018_amd64.deb
```

Here's a screenshot to clarify things:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

`curl` by default prints STDOUT to the terminal, hence the file you're fetching (in this case a binary file) is printed directly to the terminal.

What you want is to redirect STDOUT from the terminal to a file (you can do that using Bash's `>` operator):

```
curl http://files.unity3d.com/levi/unity-editor-5.2.2f1+20151018_amd64.deb > unity-editor-5.2.2f1+20151018_amd64.deb
```

[image: s1]